# BLOB files in SQL-database as chunk

Tags: c#, sql-server, blob, uniqueidentifier, chunks

I tried to modify the example from: [link to example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3517w44b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but i receive an error;
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'` 
I suppose that the returned ID (UniqueIdentifier) isn't correct.
  My code:

```
public static Guid AddRecord(string firstCol, DateTime SecCol, string photoFilePath)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Test;"))
    {
        SqlCommand addRec = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO myTable (firstCol,SecCol,Image) " +
            "VALUES (@firstCol,@SecCol,0x0)" +
            "SELECT @Identity = NEWID();" +
            "SELECT @Pointer = TEXTPTR(Image) FROM myTable WHERE ID = @Identity", connection);

        addRec.Parameters.Add("@firstCol", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = firstCol;
        addRec.Parameters.Add("@SecCol", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = SecCol;

        SqlParameter idParm = addRec.Parameters.Add("@Identity", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
        idParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        SqlParameter ptrParm = addRec.Parameters.Add("@Pointer", SqlDbType.Binary, 16);
        ptrParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        connection.Open();

        addRec.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Guid newRecID = (Guid)idParm.Value;

        StorePhoto(photoFilePath, (byte[])ptrParm.Value, connection);

        return newRecID;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mithrandir: Thx. I couldn't get the code properly formatted in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, the example is obsolete; I would not recommend using it.

If you are set on making it work just as an exercise, change your SQL to insert the ID that you created into `myTable`, as follows:

```
SqlCommand addRec = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT @Identity = NEWID();" +
            "INSERT INTO myTable (ID,firstCol,SecCol,Image) " +
            "VALUES (@Identity,@firstCol,@SecCol,0x0)" +
            "SELECT @Pointer = TEXTPTR(Image) FROM myTable WHERE ID = @Identity", connection);
```

Comment: Works exelent. But if it can be done better for my 'Windows Form Application'. Please advice me.

Comment: @Robertico The `TEXTPTR` feature [is on its way out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176068.aspx), so I think a better way to slice your image and load it would be to use [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)'s [`Offset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.offset.aspx) property. Unfortunately, Microsoft does not offer a good example for it, so you would need to search around for a good walk-through.

Answer (score 1):

That example is obsolete. USe of `TEXTPTR` is strongly discouraged after SQL Server 2005, along with the deprecated TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE types. The correct SQL Server 2005 and after method of efficiently manipulating BLOBs is to use `UPDATE .WRITE` syntax and MAX data types.  If you want to see an example look at [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: My app. is a 'Windows Form Application' and the server SQL-server 2008 R2. Database column type is 'Image'. It's not possible to change the type.

Answer (score 1):

I found a much better way [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/dc1b053d-f0d5-48f8-ad82-fb6d96d27f80), this is the SQL Server 2005 + way todo it.

```
string sql = "UPDATE BinaryData SET Data.Write(@data, LEN(data), @length) WHERE fileName=@fileName";

        SqlParameter dataParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
        SqlParameter lengthParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@length", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int readBytes = 0;
        while (cIndex < fileSize)
        {
            if (cIndex + BUFFER_SIZE > fileSize)
                readBytes = fileSize - cIndex;
            else
                readBytes = BUFFER_SIZE;
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, readBytes);

            dataParam.Value = buffer;
            dataParam.Size = readBytes;
            lengthParam.Value = readBytes;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cIndex += BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
```

*BinaryData* is the table name.

*Data.Write* is a system function call where *Data* is a column name